# How to use @Viewbuilder and return view in swiftUi?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have overlay with below code

```
.overlay(abcViewModel.isError ? AnyView(DialogBoxOneButton(accessibilityID: "dialogboxes", dialogboxType: .error, dialogboxTitle: "title", dialogboxBody: "body", dialogboxFirstButtonTitle: "title", dialogboxFirstButtonCallback: {
    action()
    abcViewModel.isError = false
}, isDialogboxFirstButtonClicked: .constant(true))) :  AnyView(EmptyView()))
```

I am trying to avoid use of Anyview and did below code but getting error as "Unknown attribute 'Viewbuilder'" and not sure how to return view in if case

```
private func getOverlayView() -> some View {
     if abcViewModel.isError {
          DialogBoxOneButton(accessibilityID: "dialogboxes", dialogboxType: .error, dialogboxTitle: "title", dialogboxBody: "body", dialogboxFirstButtonTitle: "title", dialogboxFirstButtonCallback: {
              action()
              abcViewModel.isError = false
          }, isDialogboxFirstButtonClicked: .constant(true))
    } else {
       return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Kindly help me the best way for this

Comment: yeah that's my question how to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@ViewBuilder` to the computed property/function creating the overlay view.

```
@ViewBuilder
private var overlay: some View {
    if abcViewModel.isError {
        DialogBoxOneButton(accessibilityID: "dialogboxes", dialogboxType: .error, dialogboxTitle: "title", dialogboxBody: "body", dialogboxFirstButtonTitle: "title", dialogboxFirstButtonCallback: {
             action()
             abcViewModel.isError = false
         }, isDialogboxFirstButtonClicked: .constant(true))
    } else {
       EmptyView()
    }
}
```

and then pass this property to `overlay`

```
.overlay(overlay)
```

Comment: can i create function and do same ? instead of creating var property ?

Comment: @NewiOSDev yes, but unless you need to pass input arguments, there's no need to make that a function, a computed property simplifies the call site

Comment: `@ViewBuilder private func createOverlay() -> some View {` does the trick if you really want a function

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@ViewBuilder` above your function signature like:

```
@ViewBuilder private func createOverlay() -> some View { ... }
```

And get rid of all `return` keywords.

---

#### Cleaner method

You can extend the `View` and define a simple function and hide any view conditionally like:

```
extension View {

    @ViewBuilder
    func hidden(if condition: Bool) -> some View {
        if condition { self.hidden() }
        else { self }
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
DialogBoxOneButton(...)
    .hidden(if: !abcViewModel.isError)
```